# How to install PHP extensions on a remote Linux server

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

as the title says, I wrote a PHP code to connect to a remote SQL SERVER and works fine on my machine since I have the necessary extensions installed locally on my machine but this script won't run in the remote Linux server where I plan to host it, and so far I haven't found any useful solution so how do I get to install the extensions on the remote Linux machine so as the script will work. Any help will be highly appreciated and also thanx in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow! Please note that this site deals with programming questions. For server administration, see [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Ok noted @ventiseis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install them via SSH if you have access to the remote server.
Use linux console or download PUTTY SSH client for windows to connect after this you can work on remote server as on a local machine.

Of course it is only text based, without UI.